How to mock New-AzStorageContext in Pester
I would like to mock New-AzStorageContext to return a value that can be used as the DestContext parameter of the function Start-AzStorageBlobCopy.
I have tried New-MockObject of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext and New-MockObject of IStorageContext and creating my fake own class that inherits from IStorageContext.
All lead to different dead ends.
How can I mock the function New-AzStorageContext to return a value that I can use as the DestContext parameter of the function Start-AzStorageBlobCopy?


How to mock New-AzStorageContext in Pester

I mock New-AzStorageContext using below script and I followed Microsoft Doc1 and Microsoft Doc2:
Firstly, I have installed and imported Pester module:
Install-Module -Name Pester -Force -SkipPublisherCheck -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Module Pester -RequiredVersion 5.6.1

Then stored below script in pestest.ps1 :
Describe "Start-AzStorageBlobCopy with mocked New-AzStorageContext,Rithwik" {
    Mock New-AzStorageContext {
        $rith_mk_Cxt = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
            StorageAccountName = 'rithwik_mock_Storage'
            AccountKey = 'rithmockkey=='
        }
        return $rith_mk_Cxt
    }

    It "should mock New-AzStorageContext and use it in Start-AzStorageBlobCopy, Rithwik" {
        $rith_mk_Cxt = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'rithwik_mock_Storage' -StorageAccountKey 'rithmockkey=='
        $rith_mk_Cxt | Should -Not -BeNullOrEmpty
        $rith_mk_Cxt.StorageAccountName | Should -Be 'rithwik_mock_Storage'
        Mock Start-AzStorageBlobCopy {
            Param (
                $SourceUri,
                $DestContainer,
                $DestBlob,
                $DestContext
            )

            $DestContext | Should -Not -BeNullOrEmpty
            $DestContext.StorageAccountName | Should -Be 'rithwik_mock_Storage'
        }
        Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -SourceUri "https://rithmocksource.blob.core.windows.net" `
                               -DestContainer "rithmockcontainer" `
                               -DestBlob "rithmockblob" `
                               -DestContext $rith_mk_Cxt
        Assert-MockCalled Start-AzStorageBlobCopy
    }
}

Then executed above script using below command:
& "C:\Users\path\pestest.ps1"

Output:


Thanks.  I attempted to break this into two files Copy.psm1 and Copy.Tests.ps1 and was not able to reproduce success.  I then stepped through it a bit and became skeptical that the mocking was actually mocking.
I added Assert-MockCalled New-AzStorageContext and it failed.
I commented out the 'Mock New-AzStorageContext' and it seemed as though the behavior did not change.
Thoughts?

Why aren't you using my script? It worked perfectly fine for me. Try copy pasting at first then try integrating into others, so it will be helpful for you to understand it. My test is passed , so try this way.



Why aren't you using my script? <<
Because I do not/can't have the production code and test code in the same file?


I did take it directly at first but I do get the error of "An error occured running Pester: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters." which gave me a clue that the New-AzStorageContext is not actually being mocked.

Try to give any base64 value for the account key, as it expects base64. Even for mocking you need to give what it expects.

If you are using 2 files then you should import the first file into second file. First line should be something like this Import-Module -Name "C:\downloads\rith.psm1" -Force

It does not "expect" a Base-64 string, it expects a string.  There is no such data type as a Base-64 string.  The mocking is not working for that function, which in turn means it is not working in general.

Can you provide your code ( 2 files) ? so that community can help you
